# Basic Bayesian updating priors

Tags: prior

I have a question about simple Bayesian reasoning.

Suppose there are N datasets, two mutually exclusive models, priors for models can be chosen as 0.5 to 0.5.

The datasets have different characteristics and can not be mixed. Among two models, only one is true for all of the datasets.

So, Bayesian updating: I test one dataset and update priors, than take the other dataset. But when should I stop? Should I re-test datasets in a recursive way until convergence, or stop when all N datasets will pass updating procedure?

Comment: What do you mean by the datasets cannot be mixed?

Comment: @Xi'an they can not be analysed together. They have different and non-linear correlation structure. So mixing them and testing at once is not an option - each time I fit statistical models and perform kinda likelihood ratio test, taking priors into account.

Comment: If they relate to the same parameter, they must be analysed together.

Comment: @Xi'an I think I explained myself not so good. They have different and complex underlying dependencies - unique for each dataset. Intra-group variabilities are small, but the variability between groups is huge. If I will just mix them - I will have huge variances and will not be able to fit statistical models. I also can not properly model covariates and mix cleaned data - the dependencies are not linear.

Comment: @GermanDemidov Did you ever figure out the solution to your question?